# Possible to create single pixel wide horizontal/vertical ttk.Separator's?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, separator, ttk

Is there a way to create single pixel wide horizontal and vertical ttk.Separator()'s?

Python 2.7/Windows: When I magnify the ttk Separators they are built as 2 parallel lines - one line gray and one line a light/white color. The latter color added to create a subtle 3d effect?

I would like to create single pixel wide separators that have the system default gray color. A bonus would be the ability to programmatically discover the system color used for a separator's gray band.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a single pixel line, create a normal frame with a width of 1. It will have the default gray background. If you want the background of the root window you can always just ask:

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
print "background is", root["background"]
```

Comment: The ttk.Separator()'s color is different than the root's background color. Otherwise, the separator would be invisible? Is there a way to determine the ttk.Separator's gray color (so we can create a matching frame color?) I'm wondering if there's a platform portable way to determine such a color via a named constant in a manner similar in principle to TKinter's system font names? Thanks for the tip about using a 1 pixel wide Frame as a separator.